# Disabling DHCP on startup

Tags: boot, networking, server, kernel, dhcp

My problem is that my server takes 2-3 minutes to boot up fully, this is due to the 'DHCP Loading page'.
Without setting a static IP, how can I either disable this on bootup, or decrease the timeout?

For reference I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Are you talking about the server?

Comment: Yes, the server.

Comment: Can you describe a little more what you mean by *"the 'DHCP Loading page'"*? What kind of network is this in (home LAN?, workplace?) and how did you configure the server's network parameters?

Comment: Sorry, the DHCP loading page I mean is similar to that in this image:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dhcp+loading+page+ubuntu+startup&espv=2&biw=1600&bih=771&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkv9qF6p7OAhVpB8AKHT6TBGQQ_AUICCgD#imgrc=FuL_hfXDhsebYM%3A

It is home LAN, what do you mean by the network parameters?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you're referring to (eventually) existing questions and information, share your research with proper references and explanations why existing solutions don't work _or_ (much less preferred) remove the notion that those exist since users have to do this work for you instead or will (much more likely) downvote your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First, disable Network Manager service, and enable systemd-networkd and systemd-resolved service:

```
exec sudo -i
systemctl disable NetworkManager
systemctl enable systemd-networkd
systemctl enable systemd-resolved
systemctl start systemd-resolved
rm /etc/resolv.conf
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Second, configure Network Connections with Systemd-networkd and assign a static IP address to a network interface:

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/network
touch /etc/systemd/network/10-static-enp3s0.network
nano /etc/systemd/network/10-static-enp3s0.network
```

Each network configuration file contains one or more "sections" with each section preceded by [XXX] heading. Each section contains one or more key/value pairs. To assign a static IP address to a network interface, put the following content:

```
[Match]
Name=enp3s0

[Network]
Address=192.168.10.50/24
Gateway=192.168.10.1
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

For example, in this file the interface enp3s0 will be assigned an address 192.168.10.50/24, a default gateway 192.168.10.1, and a DNS server 8.8.8.8. Replace them with yours parameters.

Once you are done with creating configuration files reboot.